# Dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 on a system with two disks

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, windows-10

My laptop specification is:

- Intel® Core™ i7-8550U (1.8 GHz base frequency, up to 4 GHz with Intel® Turbo Boost Technology, 8 MB cache, 4 cores)
- 16 GB DDR4-2400 SDRAM (2 x 8 GB)
- NVIDIA® GeForce® MX150 (4 GB GDDR5 dedicated)
- 128GB SSD + 1TB 5400 rpm SATA

My Windows 10 was installed on my SSD disk, I shrank 200 GB of my second disk, and I installed Ubuntu 18.04. I allocated 50 GB for my root and 150 GB for my home. After restarting my laptop, I can't see dual boot!

I would be grateful if anybody helps me.

Comment: Which OS doesn't boot, Windows 10, Ubuntu 18.04 or both OSs? Do you get a grub boot menu when booting?

Comment: My Ubuntu doesn't boot. I got grub.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: Yes, that is exactly my problem